# "django-admin.py startproject Concept" doesn't work in virtualenv

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, virtualenv

First of all I want to assure you that I have in fact python 3.5.1 and django 1.9.
I installed python with an installer which automatically added python to my PATH (I have checked this).
I ran into a problem with pip,
Every time in CMD when I enter, even the word pip the cmd window just stands still, no error, nothing, it is just pretending to load, doesn't even let me type in anything else, can't even be "ended" with Task Manager.
Eventually I found a work-around with

```
python -m pip install virtualenv
```

That worked, I made a ENV, activated it, installed django with the same command, but now when I try to enter this command:

```
django-admin.py startproject Concept
```

It doesn't work, if I try with

```
python django-admin.py startproject Concept
```

It will say that the file is missing.
Every time I run this command in my text editor, sublime 3, the django-admin,py file opens, at the top of the document I saw

```
#!C:\Users\filip\Python\ENV\Scripts\python.exe
```

So, I tried changing it to

```
#!C:\Users\filip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe
```

That didn't work either, hope you can help.

Comment: `installed django with the same command`, which command?

Comment: python -m pip install django

Answer (score 0):

```
python C:\Users\filip\Python\ENV\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject Concept
```

This works, apparently it is a Windows bug.

Comment: it is not windows bug!! you need to setup environment variables correctly! and you dont need `python` here in first position

Comment: Well, that obviously doesn't work, and the environment variables should be set up correctly,
I can type in python in cmd and have the interpreter activate and even import pip, so that should be fine.

Comment: C:\Users\filip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\;
C:\Users\filip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\;
C:\Users\filip\Python\ENV\Lib\site-packages\django\bin
I have all of these added in my Path and PATH and it still doesn't work.